# How can a UIView subclass get notified when it has been scrolled by its Superview UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to subclass `UIView` and to get notified when its superviews got scrolled. I tried with `UIScrollView` `DidScroll` delegate, But I want to create a standalone `UIView` to handle its movement on screen by itself. I tried by iterating its superviews and adding KVO for each superviews, but it might lead to performance issues. Can you please suggest some better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol for delegation, that you can set in parent UIViewController and implement function in sub view class. and call these protocol function from UIScrollView delegate method.

This should solve your problem

Comment: But I am creating this as Library, I am trying to avoid tight couple with the app. I need to observe for any scroll events happening inside the App.